# Выполнение метода раз в 24 часа . SWIFT

Tags: swift, label, app

Есть приложение где пользователь должен потрусить телефон и получить Label с текстом. Как   сделать  , что бы пользователь мог делать это только  раз в день ??

Вот код класса.

import UIKit

extension Date {

```
    func isOutdated(forHours hours: Int) -> Bool {
    let plusHours = self.dateByAddingHours(hours)
    return plusHours.lessThan(Date())
}   
func dateByAddingHours(_ dHours: NSInteger) -> Date {
    let aTimeInterval = self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate + Double(3600) * Double(dHours)
    let newDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: aTimeInterval)
    return newDate
}  
func lessThan(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
    return self.compare(date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}
```

}

class PredictionViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var predictLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shareHidden: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nameAppPredictLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var namePredictLabel: UILabel!

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

    shareHidden.isHidden = false
    predictLabel.center.x = self.view.frame.width  + 50


    if (motion == .motionShake) {

        saveDate()

        shakePhoneLabelOutlet.isHidden = true
        namePredictLabel.text = Singleton.shared.nameUser

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "predict", ofType: "txt")

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        let  msgString = contentString.components(separatedBy: ".").randomElement()!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")

        self.predictLabel.text = msgString
        }      
    }

@IBAction func shareAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let activityVC =  UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [namePredictLabel.text!,":", predictLabel.text!,nameAppPredictLabel.text!], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion:  nil    )
}
func saveDate()
{    let key = "toDate"
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: key)
    let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as! Date
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    print(df.string(from: date)) 
    date.isOutdated(forHours: 24)    
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После сработки первого события вы можете сохранять текущее время (Date) в UserDefautls.

Далее при повторных событиях вы сравниваете текущее время с сохраненным в UserDefaults и проверяете, прошло ли 24 часа.

Несколько функций для решения вашей задачи:

```
extension Date {

    /// Отстает ли сохраненное врем более чем на hours часов от текущей
        func isOutdated(forHours hours: Int) -> Bool {
            let plusHours = self.dateByAddingHours(hours)
            return plusHours.lessThan(Date())
        }

        func dateByAddingHours(_ dHours: NSInteger) -> Date {
            let aTimeInterval = self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate + Double(3600) * Double(dHours)
            let newDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: aTimeInterval)
            return newDate
        }

        func lessThan(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
            return self.compare(date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
        }
  }
```

Пример

savedDate - ваша сохраненная в UserDefaults.

savedDate.isOutdated(forHours: 24) - вернет вам результат

---

У вас смешалось все, необходимо следующее

```
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

          shareHidden.isHidden = false
          predictLabel.center.x = self.view.frame.width  + 50

          if (motion == .motionShake) {
               makeActionIfNeeded()
          }      
    }


    func actionAfterShake() {
         saveDate()
         shakePhoneLabelOutlet.isHidden = true
         namePredictLabel.text = Singleton.shared.nameUser

         let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "predict", ofType: "txt")
         let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
         let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
         let  msgString = contentString.components(separatedBy: ".").randomElement()!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
         self.predictLabel.text = msgString
    }
    // cохраняем текущее время
    func saveDate()
    {    let key = "toDate"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: key)
    }

    // Проверяем, прошло ли 24 часа, если прошло, то выполняем действие
    func makeActionIfNeeded() {
        let key = "toDate"
        let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Date
        if date?.isOutdated(forHours: 24) ?? false {
             actionAfterShake()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ваш код очень помог, но я не совсем понимаю как им воспользоваться. 
Я  попытался в функцию где сохраняю дату, добавить date.isOutdated(forHours: 24) и потом эту функцию поместить в событие , но это не помогло, я все еще могу трусить и получать label с текстом сколько угодно.

Я напишу код  класса к вопросу сверху . Может скажете что я не так написал.

Comment: @GlebSeredyuk я обновил свой ответ - посмотрите.

Comment: Я переделал свой код на такой как у вас и я думаю что это то что мне нужно, но в строке 
' let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as! Date'
Выдаёт ошибку- Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Date может и не быть в UserDefaults, а вы использовали "as! Date" - это называется force cast, когда вы используете ! - вы говорите, что данные точно есть.

Вам необходимо использовать "?".
Рекомендую почитать об этом подробнее в интернете, статей на эту тему очень много.

Comment: Когда я поменял на '..as? Date'   в условии 
'  if date.isOutdated(forHours: 24)' 
Выдаёт ошибку : (Value of optional type 'Date?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'isOutdated' of wrapped base type 'Date')

предлагало два варианта решений 
1)Chain the optional using '?' to access member 'isOutdated' only for non-'nil' base values
2)Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

я перепробовал несколько вариантов, но ошибка остаётся уже на этой строке с if...

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста на то, как написано у меня в ответе, где код.

Comment: @EugenLezov     Ваш код мне очень помог . Но в условии if нужно было поставить true иначе оно  пропускало, код где считывался файл. Спасибо еще раз за подсказки !

Comment: @EugenLezov , могли бы вы подсказать как из этого кода сделать так, что бы лейбл обновлялся автоматически каждый день  в 12 часов ночи ?
Пример : Пользователь открыл первый раз приложение и там уже видно текст , он остаётся пока не 12 часов ночи , если 12 часов , то  функция считывает фал и текст меняется

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте уведомление на событие "трусить". При получении уведомления,получаете ранее сохраненную дату из UserDefaults. Сравниваете её с текущей датой. Если прошло 24 часа, выводите лейбл, а текущую дату сохраняете в UserDefaults. Если не прошло 24 часа - ничего не делаете и return из метода обработки уведомления.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий . Сегодня попробую, если получиться выставлю код .

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к тому, что предложил @NSA-bot, я бы использовал DispacthQueue.global(.utility), ибо, если я не ошибаюсь, информация в этом потоке грузится очень долго, поэтому пользователь сможет смотреть ее только раз в день.